# how to Seed a MongoDB database without getting 'null''s

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have for hours to find a solution to this with no luck. I am a beginner which doesn't help. Below is the JSON output after running seed from the command line (windows).

```js
{
   "_id":"57f4fc5adf7e1109b08660d4",
   "companyName":"Flat Iron",
   "contactName":"Phil",
   "userName":"Hook",
   "email":"bill@reds",
   "phone":"12345678910",
   "image":"url6",
   "meals":[
      {
         "_id":"57f4fc5adf7e1109b08660d1",
         "name":"Burger and chips",
         "upvotes":5,
         "downvotes":20,
         "price":16,
         "official":true,
         "__v":0,
         "images":[
            "google.com/url3"
         ],
         "ingredients":[
            "egg",
            "water",
            "GF dough",
            "beef"
         ],
         "suitable_for":[
            "fodmap"
         ],
         "add_for_taste":[
            "asoefida",
            "orange",
            "pineapple"
         ],
         "remove_for_safe":[
            "garlic",
            "wheat"
         ],
         "favourited_by":[
            null
         ]
      }
   ],
   "locations":[
      "NW16BG",
      "EN41RT"
   ],
   "caters_for":[
      "scd",
      "paleo",
      "fodmap"
   ]
}
]
```

Below is my Seeds file. From the above you can see that 'favourited_by' returns null, but gets the right number of objects (or 'nulls').

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var databaseURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/tda';
mongoose.connect(databaseURL);

// var Project = require("../models/project"); 
var User    = require("../models/user");
var Vendor  = require("../models/vendor");
var Meal    = require("../models/meal");

// This will clear what ever we have in the database :) 
User.collection.drop();
Vendor.collection.drop();
Meal.collection.drop();

var meal1 = new Meal({
  name: "Nice Meal",
  upvotes: 15,
  downvotes: 3,    
  vendor: "Flat Iron",
  favourited_by: [user1, user2],
  price: 12,
  remove_for_safe: ["onions", "cheese"],
  add_for_taste: ["carrots"],
  suitable_for: ["paleo", "fodmap", "SCD"],
  ingredients: ["egg", "water", "cress"],
  images: ["google.com/url"],
  official: true
})




var meal2 = new Meal({
  name: "Good meal",
  upvotes: 35,
  downvotes: 23,    
  vendor: "McDonalds",
  favourited_by: [user1, user2, user3],
  price: 6,
  remove_for_safe: ["onions", "gherkins"],
  add_for_taste: ["carrots", "peas", "water"],
  suitable_for: ["paleo", "fodmap"],
  ingredients: ["egg", "water", "GF Bread", "burger"],
  images: ["google.com/url2"],
  official: false
})





var meal3 = new Meal({
  name: "Burger and chips",
  upvotes: 5,
  downvotes: 20,    
  vendor: "Reds True BBQ",
  favourited_by: [user3],
  price: 16,
  remove_for_safe: ["garlic", "wheat"],
  add_for_taste: ["asoefida", "orange", "pineapple"],
  suitable_for: ["fodmap"],
  ingredients: ["egg", "water", "GF dough", "beef"],
  images: ["google.com/url3"],
  official: true
})





var vendor1 = new Vendor({
  companyName: "Reds",
  contactName: "Butch",
  userName: "Hook",
  email: "greg@greg.com",
  phone: "12345678910",
  image: "url4",
  caters_for: ["scd", "paleo", "fodmap"],
  locations: ["N213BQ", "EN41RT"],
  meals: [meal1, meal2]
})


var vendor2 = new Vendor({
  companyName: "McDonalds",
  contactName: "Tim Applebee",
  userName: "TimA",
  email: "tim@mcds.com",
  phone: "12345678910",
  image: "url5",
  caters_for: ["scd", "paleo", "fodmap"],
  locations: ["N15TG", "EC41RT"],
  meals: [meal2]
})


var vendor3 = new Vendor({
  companyName: "Flat Iron",
  contactName: "Phil",
  userName: "Hook",
  email: "bill@reds",
  phone: "12345678910",
  image: "url6",
  caters_for: ["scd", "paleo", "fodmap"],
  locations: ["NW16BG", "EN41RT"],
  meals: [meal3]
})


var user1 = new User({
  firstName: "Mick",
  lastName: "Fry",
  userName: "Mike",
  email: "mike@mike.com",
  diet: "fodmap",
  location: "London",
  profile_photo: "imageurl",
  saved_meals: [meal1, meal2],
  saved_vendors: [vendor1]
})


var user2 = new User({
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Scott",
  userName: "tascott",
  email: "scott@scott.com",
  diet: "fodmap",
  location: "Leeds",
  profile_photo: "imageurl2",
  saved_meals: [meal1, meal3],
  saved_vendors: [vendor1]
})


var user3 = new User({
  firstName: "Phil",
  lastName: "Croy",
  userName: "Croa",
  email: "paul@paul.com",
  diet: "SCD",
  location: "London",
  profile_photo: "imageurl3",
  saved_meals: [meal3],
  saved_vendors: [vendor1, vendor2, vendor3]
})




// Save the users
user1.save(function(err, user) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("User saved! ", user);
})
user2.save(function(err, user) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("User saved! ", user);
})
user3.save(function(err, user) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("User saved! ", user);
})


// Save the Vendors
vendor1.save(function(err, vendor) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("Vendor saved! ", vendor);
})
vendor2.save(function(err, vendor) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("Vendor saved! ", vendor);
})
vendor3.save(function(err, vendor) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("Vendor saved! ", vendor);
})





meal1.save(function(err, meal) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("Meal saved! ", meal);
})


meal2.save(function(err, meal) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("Meal saved! ", meal);
})



meal3.save(function(err, meal) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
 console.log("Meal saved! ", meal);
})
```

I am under the impression it is because 'favourited_by' has embedded 'Users' which are defined last in the seeds file. So when running the seed it tries to populate the Users but hasn't seen the data yet.

Can anyone help with a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you set `favourited_by` the users are undefined, that's because they are saved as null. You could try to update the meals after setting the users:

```
meal1.favourited_by = [user1._id, user2._id]
```

Also you could remove this from the meals initialisation.

Comment: I added this before //save the users at the near the bottom;
meal1.favourited_by = [user1, user2]
meal2.favourited_by = [user1, user2, user3]
meal3.favourited_by = [user3]

However now when I run node db/seeds I get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it coming. I think this happened because you have circular assignments like "meal1.favourited_by = [user1]" and the user has something like "user1.meals=[meal1]". If you need to store it both ways, you should only store the document's id. I'll update my answer to reflect it

Comment: This at least works to populate the data with the IDs so it's not null. Thanks!